# How to kill or delete the temp table created from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, query-optimization, database-performance

How to kill temp tables starting with

```
#am_wait_types______________________________________________________________________________________________________000000000002
```

in SQL Server?

The following screenshot shows the same. All the custom stored procedures which are using temp table are created with DROP temp temp table code block. But still we can see the temp tables are created and which is not clearing at the end and resulting the bad performance of SQL Server. Please advice how to overcome this issue?

```
select name, object_name(object_id) As ObjName,* 
from tempdb.sys.objects 
where name like '#%'
```

[image]

**Sample SQL Script**

```
(SELECT ((SUM(Quantity1)-SUM(Quantity2)) + SUM(Quantity3)) AS Quantity,ProductId,[Name],ISNULL(Price,0) as Price, FinalPrice,ISNULL(BatchNo,'') AS BatchNo , ISNULL(ExpiryDate,GETDATE()) AS ExpiryDate, ISNULL(Composition,'') AS Composition, ISNULL(ChemicalCompId,0) AS ChemicalCompId, ISNULL(Rack,'') AS Rack, ISNULL(RackId,0) AS RackId, ISNULL(HsnCode,'') AS HsnCode, HsnCodeId,      
    ISNULL(GstSlab,'') AS GstSlab , GstSlabId, GST, PharmacyPurchaseEntryId FROM(      
 SELECT SUM(pp.QuantityApproved) AS Quantity1,0 AS Quantity2, 0 AS Quantity3, pp.ProductId, pm.[Name], PPE.SellingMRP AS Price, ISNULL(PPE.GstMrp,0) AS FinalPrice, pp.BatchNo,       
 pp.ExpiryDate,ccm.[Name] AS Composition, pm.ChemicalCompId, ISNULL(R.Name,'') AS Rack, ISNULL(R.RackId,0) AS RackId, H.Code AS HsnCode, ISNULL(H.Id,0) AS HsnCodeId,      
 G.Code AS GstSlab,ISNULL(G.Id,0) AS GstSlabId, ISNULL(PPE.GST,0) AS GST  , pp.PharmacyPurchaseEntryId    
 FROM dbo.PharmacyStockToCounterEntry pp       
 LEFT JOIN dbo.PharmacyStockToCounterMain ppm ON pp.StocktoCounterId = ppm.StocktoCounterId       
 LEFT JOIN dbo.PharmacyPurchaseEntry PPE ON pp.ProductId = PPE.ProductId AND PPE.BatchNo = pp.BatchNo AND PPE.ExpiryDate = pp.ExpiryDate AND
 pp.PharmacyPurchaseEntryId = PPE.PharmacyPurchaseEntryId
 LEFT JOIN dbo.PharmacyMaster pm ON pp.ProductId = pm.PharmacyItemId        
 LEFT JOIN dbo.ChemicalCompoMaster ccm ON pm.ChemicalCompId = ccm.ChemicalCompoId        
 LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Rack] R ON R.CounterId = @counterId AND R.ProductId = pm.PharmacyItemId       
 LEFT JOIN HsnCode H ON H.Id = ISNULL(pm.HsnCodeId, PPE.HsnCodeId)      
 LEFT JOIN GstSlab G ON G.Id = ISNULL(pm.GstSlabId, PPE.GstSlabId)      
 WHERE ppm.IsCancel='N' AND ppm.CounterId = @counterId AND ppm.TransStatus ='A'   
)      
AS TEMP      
GROUP BY ProductId, Name, Price, FinalPrice, BatchNo, ExpiryDate, Composition, ChemicalCompId, Rack, RackId, HsnCode, GstSlab, HsnCodeId, GstSlabId, GST, PharmacyPurchaseEntryId
HAVING ((SUM(Quantity1)-SUM(Quantity2)) + SUM(Quantity3)) > 0;
```

Comment: It will be really helpful if you provide your script(like your store procedure here in this case or your query where you had used temp tables) 
From the screenshot can see there are SQL server level procedures which are often runned at the SQL level they get deleted once you terminate the connection . In you case the user tables which you had created(i.e usage of temp tables ) once the connection is terminated it will get dropped or u are closing a database conenction via c# code .
Please provide your sample code to analyse the same here

Comment: @AkshayPhadke Added the sql script for more detail. In the client application connection pooling is not enabled and the application is using this standalone server from multiple client applications located in the same network.

Comment: You need to show us the code that creates the tables like `#am_wait_types` - each session needs to clean up its own temp tables. But how do you know that they are aren't still in use and how have you concluded that they are causing performance issues?

Comment: Well if you expand temp tables you can see all the temp tables which are listed there and same there in above query result same with store procedures . those are in Tempdb and those are you can say are system defined . But as per your abpove screenshot i cannot see anything regarding your application . you can use sp_who2 you can see which one is the query where you temp table is not getting deleted

Comment: Looks like it might be this script,p erhaps running in an Agent job? https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/98552/220697. If so, it's nothing to do with the script you posted, it's that procedure which needs fixing. Otherwise, if it's your tables, just close the connection and the tables will drop automatically

Comment: "resulting the bad performance of SQL Server" - how have you traced the presence of these temp tables to bad performance? SQL Server caches temp objects, so the mere presence of these objects doesn't lead necessarily indicate a cause of performance degradation.